# Delphi FireDAC TFDQuery event 'AfterOpen' never executes

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'm trying to execute an sql query asynchronously. I've checked the example code from http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Asynchronous_Execution_(FireDAC)

and also the example project from directory

`..Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDQuery\ExecSQL\Async`

and I think I got the logic inside. But there is one problem - the event `QueryAfterOpen` never executes and my `TDataSource` remains always `Nil` (because it gets `Nil` inside `QueryBeforeOpen` - this event executes always). This is all the code from my unit :

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,   
  FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, 
  FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys,       
  FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client,    
  FireDAC.Phys.MySQLDef, FireDAC.Phys.MySQL;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  FDPhysMySQLDriverLink1: TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Query1BeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
  procedure Query1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
  procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);

private
  { Private declarations }
  Connection1: TFDConnection;
  Query1: TFDQuery;
  DataSource1: TDataSource;
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    QueryFinished: Boolean;
begin
  with Query1 do begin
    SQL.Text := 'SELECT field1 FROM test_table WHERE idpk=1';
    AfterOpen := Query1AfterOpen;
    BeforeOpen := Query1BeforeOpen;
    ResourceOptions.CmdExecMode := amAsync;
    QueryFinished := False;
    Open;
    repeat
      Sleep(100);
      if Command.State = csPrepared then begin
          // A command is prepared. A result set is not accessible.
        // TmpInteger := Query1.FieldByName('field1').AsInteger;
      end
      else if Command.State = csOpen then begin // A command execution
         // is finished. A result set is accessible and not yet fully fetched.
        if DataSource1.DataSet <> Nil then begin 
          // this code never executes because Query1AfterOpen never executes and 
          // DataSource1.DataSet remains always Nil !!!
          QueryFinished := True;
        end;
      end;
    until ((QueryFinished) OR (DataSource1.DataSet <> Nil));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    SQLConnParams: string;
  begin
    SQLConnParams := ''; // sql connection parameters removed from here from security 
    // issues, assume they are correct
    Connection1 := TFDConnection.Create(Nil);
    Connection1.Params.Text := SQLConnParams;
    Query1 := TFDQuery.Create(Nil);
    Query1.Connection := Connection1;
    DataSource1 := TDataSource.Create(Nil);
    DataSource1.DataSet := Query1;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataSource1.Free;
  Query1.Free;
  Connection1.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Query1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSource1.DataSet := Query1;
  Query1.AfterOpen := Nil;
  //Query1.ResourceOptions.CmdExecMode := amBlocking;
end;

procedure TForm1.Query1BeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSource1.DataSet := Nil;
end;
end.
```

Apparently the code inside the `repeat .. until ..` loop is infinite unless someone terminates the program. What am I missing in order to execute the code inside `Query1AfterOpen` (or use another event instead) so I can access the result set after the `TFDQuery` has finished working ?

Answer (score 1):

Those asynchronous events are synchronized with the main thread via the message loop. As long as you stay inside the `Button1Click` event no new messages can be handled. Thus the AfterOpen event is stuck inside the message loop.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but you should consider placing the relevant code in the AfterOpen event. The repeat-until clause somehow counterfeits the purpose of that async execution.

Comment: I'm waiting for the query to finish it's work and return a result set or cancel it's work if something happens (for example someone raises an exception  flag) - that's why I'd like to use asynchronous ``TFDQuery``. I just took the code from a bigger project and placed it inside ``Button1Click`` - but let's assume that ``Button1Click`` is a procedure that is executed inside a ``TThread.Execute`` event.

Comment: If you are waiting for the query to finish you should better stick to `amBlocking` as that is exactly what you need here. `amAsync` only makes sense when you don't need the result set directly after the call to `open`. Interestingly your code would probably work as expected when you actually did place it inside a `TThread.Execute' method, because in that case you are not blocking the message queue. You will have other problems with syncing variable access though.

Comment: But it's still not working - the ``Query1AfterOpen`` event is still never reached.